# GraphQL: How to reuse a "individual object" resolver to load an array of same objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I have two queries, one to get a single project and one to get array of projects

```js
extend type Query{
  allProjects: [Project!]
  oneProject(id:ID!):Project
}
```

I have written individual resolvers for the project object fields. My goal was that only those fields are loaded that were actually requested. I used this tutorial https://medium.com/paypal-tech/graphql-resolvers-best-practices-cd36fdbcef55

```js
export const resolvers: IResolvers = {
  Query: {
    async oneProject(_, { id }) {
      return { id };
    },
  },
  Project: {
    name: async ({ id }) => {
      const { name } = await projectLoader.load(id);
      return name;
    },
    description: async ({ id }) => {
      const { description } = await projectLoader.load(id);
      return description;
    },
    task: async ({ id }) => {
      const { task } = await projectLoader.load(id);
      const resolvedTask = taskLoader.load(task)
      return resolvedTask;
    },

    ...
}
```

I use dataloader, to avoid loading the project every time a field resolver is executed.

With all that logic in place, how do I best implement the 2nd query to get all projects? Is it somehow possible to pass the ids of all projects to my already implemented resolver that handles individual projects?
If not, I'd have to implement the same logic that I 've implemented for the individual resolver again.
The ultimate aim remains to only load the requested fields and not all fields and to use the dataloader. Dataloader is  important as I have other types including a person type which is references by many other (and I try to avoid loading of the same person multiple times).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your `projectLoader.load(id)` does load the whole object with all fields (`name`, `description`) anyway, it's probably better and simpler to put that call right in the `oneProject` resolver.

Comment: Hi Bergi, if I put `projectLoader.load(id)` in the `oneProject` resolver,  all fields will be loaded for every request/all the time, even if that request is only asking for the name. Unfortunately, I have fields that reference other complex types which are costly to load from the db and I want to avoid loading them they are not even requested.

Comment: But if you put `projectLoader.load(id)` in the `name` resolver, it does *still* load all fields even if the request is only asking for the name?

Comment: "*I'd have to implement the same logic that I've implemented for the individual resolver again.*" - uh, all the logic you've implemented in `oneProject(_, { id })` is `return { id };`. It's not worth it to avoid duplication there… All your hypothetical `allProjects` resolver needs to do is load the list of all projects, and then return an array of objects with an `id` property.

Comment: Hi Bergi, `projectLoader.load(id)` does indeed load all fields but from cache and not from db. This is the price for e.g. testability (please have a look at the linked article).

Comment: Hi Bergi, the reason `oneProject` only returns the `id` is that this is all info required by the field resolvers to get the project and therefore the respective field info. 
Now if you are saying that if the `allProjects` resolver returns an array of project ids and this array is picked up by the field resolvers from the `Project` resolver and this all together results in an array of populated project objects ... awesome, that is what I was hoping for! But is this behavior what is supposed to happen? I did not manage to replicate that behavior in  my code. Thanks

Comment: I really disagree with that article. "*Fetching and passing data from parent-to-child should be used sparingly.*" is not a best practice. It should absolutely be used if all child resolvers fetch the same data - it will be simpler and faster (even with caching). Also it will be more correct - the parent resolver is responsible for checking whether the project actually exists, otherwise `query { oneProject(id: "does-not-exist") { id } }` will happily return an object where it should've returned `null`. (This was also remarked in the comments on that medium post).

Comment: "*But is this behavior what is supposed to happen?*" - yes, that's how list resolvers work. "*I did not manage to replicate that behavior in my code.*" - please [edit] your question to include that code.

Comment: Hi Bergi, after your last comment, I studied my code but couldn't find any errors. So I set up a new environment on another laptop, ran my code and it was working as expected. I have no idea what was wrong with my initial environment but at least it is working now. Thanks for your help and on your article feedback!